# Ruby on Rails: Porcentagem do Total nao funciona

Tags: ruby, porcentagem

gente preciso calcular quantos % dos survivors (endpoint) foram abduzidos e quantos não foram, mas nao tenho ideia de como fazer mas nao deu certo, nao sei se declarei errado tambem no routes...fiz esse método aqui no model

```
def percentage_abducted
if(abducted == true )
return abducted/servivor.all * 100
else
return abducted/servivor.all * 100
end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Não da para entender exatamente a sua logica por exemplo o seu if e o else estão fazendo a mesma coisa. Este servivor.all o servivor é um model?

Se for um model creio eu que a melhor forma forma seria iterar o resultado do servivor e fazer o calculo por linha.

```
def percentage_abducted     
 if(abducted == true )
  calc = Array.new
  serv = servivor.all
  serv.each_with_index do |value, index|
    calc[index] = abducted/value*100
  end
 end
end
```

Não precisa usar o return pois o ruby já entende que a ultima linha executada é o retorno do método.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que uma solução possível seria receber um array e iterar sobre ele da seguinte maneira (dentro da sua função porcentage_abducetd):

```
#Exemplo de sobreviventes, no caso o seu viria do argumento da função 
survivors = [true,false,true,false]

#Declarando as variáveis que irão armazenar temporariamente os valores que serão usados ao iterar nosso array
abudcteds = 0
not_abudcteds = 0

# Iterando o array e separando sobreviventes por abducted ou not_abducteds
survivors.each do |survivor|
  if survivor
    abudcteds = abudcteds + 1
  else
    not_abudcteds = not_abudcteds + 1
  end 
end

#Imprimindo o resultado
puts "abudcteds % = #{abudcteds.to_f/survivors.size * 100}%, not_abudcteds % = #{not_abudcteds.to_f/survivors.size*100}%"
```

Resultado no console:

```
abudcteds % = 50.0%, not_abudcteds % = 50.0%
```